# Display text in shiny app using ggplotly()

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Is there a way to display text in shiny app through ggplotly()?I want to pass some features that require ggplotly() later and I would like to know if this is possible.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel("HTML"),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("testHTML"),
      plotlyOutput("PLOTLYTEXT")
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$testHTML <- renderText({
    "text"
  })
  output$PLOTLYTEXT<-renderPlotly({
    p<-renderText({
      "text"
    })
    ggplotly(p)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Probably not the way you tried. `ggplotly` expects a ggplot object. Hence one option would be create a ggplot to display the text which could then be passed to ggplotly. But given the provided information I don't know whether this fits your use case.

Comment: tnx could you provide a solution of your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment one option to display text via `ggplotly` would be to create a `ggplot` using e.g. a `geom_text` to display your text which could then be converted to a `plotly` object:

```r
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("HTML"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("testHTML"),
      plotlyOutput("PLOTLYTEXT")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$testHTML <- renderText({
    "text"
  })
  output$PLOTLYTEXT<-renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, label = "text")) +
      geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)) +
      theme_void()
    ggplotly(p)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8289
```

[image]